# Проверка на ошибки, выход из цикла

Tags: c++, циклы

Можно ли сделать так, что при вводе числа программа выполняется до тех пор, пока не будет введена комбинация клавиш, например Ctrl+Z, но при этом выполняется проверка, если введен символ, то программа выводит сообщение об ошибке и заново запрашивает ввод числа?

```
while (true) {
    cout << "Input your number: ";
    cin >> value;
    if (!cin.good())
    {
        if (value == 'q')
            exit(0);
        else
        {
        while (!cin)
        {
            cin.clear();
            while (cin.get() != '\n')
                continue;
            cout << "Error!\n";
            cout << "Input your number: ";
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так сделать можно.

Comment: @AGS17 А можно пример, каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: а можно увидеть ваш код?

Comment: Организуйте вечный цикл. Внутри него спрашивайте нужный символ. Затем проверяете его, и если он корректен — выходите из цикла. А уже после этого цикла делаете остальные действия. Сочетание же клавиш `Ctrl+Z` — это признак окончания потока. Отлавливайте его так же, как вы отлавливали конец файла при чтении из него.

Comment: @AGS17, вы злой. Вопрос-то полезен не только вопрошающему, но и вообще любому, решившему сделать повторный запрос при ошибочном вводе.

Comment: @Arhad злой? Я всего лишь попросил код. А если честно - не очень приятно помогать человеку, который сам не пытается решить проблему. Поэтому я и попросил код, чтобы решить, помогать или поискать людей, которые хотят учиться, а не решенного задания, и помочь им.

Comment: @Гриша добавил код в вопрос. В следующий раз пользуйтесь кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/678402/edit) для обновления вопроса.

Comment: @AGS17 ок, спасибо

Comment: @AGS17 Как не пробовал, получается либо выход при любом не числовом вводе, либо вообще нет выхода

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  string stringValue;
  double numericValue;

  while (true) {
    cout << "Input your number: ";
    if ( std::cin >> numericValue ) {
      // если введено число продолжаем ввод
    } else {
      // пробуем считать строку из введенного значения
      std::cin.clear(); // очищаем буфер!
      if ((std::cin >> stringValue) ) {
        if (stringValue == "q") {
          exit(0);
        } else {
          cout << "Enter numner or 'q' for exit:" << endl;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```